# Unable to get Azure Vault key secrets in VSTS Release - Failed to obtain JWT

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-keyvault

I have created Azure key vault - with couple of secrets . please find below [image: ![enter image description here]

Able to authenticate from my VSTS release pipeline and couldnt get the values

[image]

When i click on "ADD" to choose secrets - I ended up with error below [image]

Could you please help on how to debug this ?

Comment: Have you added the SP access in the Key Vault's Access Policies?

Comment: Yes, using this - https://lnx.azurewebsites.net/azure-key-vault-access-policies-management-with-azure-ad-service-principal/

Comment: Can you still reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to obtain the Josn Web Token(JWT) for service principal id.

According to the error message you have shown, it may has two possibilities.

First, you SPN key has expired.You could go to `AAD > App Registrations > your app > Keys` channel and choose `Never expires` when you generate the key.

Second, the SPN itself is like a user in Azure AD, **by default it has no rights**. You could provide it "contribute" permissions, if you wish to use the SPN to create or update resources in Azure.

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/5458).

Comment: Thanks . I have tried them , still I get the same error